# Any recommendations for a good online lecture series on Metric Spaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

Any recommendations for a good online lecture series on Metric Spaces?

I have been browsing the internet for lecture videos on Metric Spaces,but most of them are not in English.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A short (but nice) introduction to the subject can be found at Analysis II by Terence Tao.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some YouTube videos I came across with a quick search. Note: I have not watched these videos so I don't know how helpful or relevant they'll be!

- [Introduction to Metric Spaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etP21xln8iQ&list=PLAvgI3H-gclZa-DVTMyUIAxM-X8NSikwu) by Ben1994. This is part of a playlist titled "Topology and Analysis" which is over 8 hours long!
- [Topology of Metric Spaces](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLm5dVnU9cyeL4-7gDAiJufuv6MSUtH8nd), a playlist by Sushrut Mane.

From what I can tell, these playlists don't cover many "advanced topics" in metric space theory – you'll probably have to read a book for that sort of thing. But if you're just looking to understand metric spaces at a basic level as a foundation for point-set topology or analysis, these could be good resources.